# M.2 nvme ssd boot

Tags: usb, boot, pi-4

Can anyone please help me out on how to setup/configure or point me in the right direction of publication on how to get my RPI4 to boot from M.2 nvme ssd specifically it is a WD Blue
Operating system is kali Linux

I have tried direct connection to the pie from the adapter enclosure being USB C to USB A3.0

As well as thru and independent powers USB hub

I have read in several places that boot from ssd is now default and also tried numerous updates and configurations from different publications but nothing has worked for me

Apologies if this has already been covered in detail, use of RPI is incredibly new to me